# Recess Framework GET send sentence

Tags: rest, http-get, recess

The following is a Recess Framework code in which I am facing problem.

```
/** !Route GET, /abc/$text */
    function xyz($text) {
```

If `$text` is a sentence. How do we get a sentence through HTTP GET. I am able to send only single word right now unlike normal URL GET where I can type + to add more words.

Answer (score 0):

IN RECESS its a REST API call and GET is used to get a response for a query.

mostly we pass an ID through the URL which is the primary key of the db.